# Why does elasticsearch not return documents which contain almost equivalent word?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, search, text, full-text-search

I want to use elasticsearch to search for documents that are relevant to the searched words provided by a user (*documents text is in dutch, also assume the words searched by the users are also in dutch*).

I also use synonyms to return same documents for searched words that are spelled differently but mean the same thing in dutch language. I stored those synonyms in synonyms.txt file in config folder of elasticsearch.

To test whether the search works properly, I used the word `loopbaan` as an example of what the user might search. Furthermore, in synonyms.txt file I linked this word with its synonyms which is `carriere`. this is done in this format:

```
...
loopbaan, carriere
...
```

now when I analyze `loopbaan` using the analyzer, like so:

```
GET /documents/_analyze
{
    "analyzer": "test_analyzer",
    "text": "loopbaan"
}
```

I get following result:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "loopban",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "carrier",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "SYNONYM",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I know that `loopbaan` is converted to `loopban` because I use the dutch stemmer, **BUT** `loopban` does **NOT** mean the same thing as `loopbaan` in dutch and is **NOT** present in any text that I have indexed in the *documents* index.

Thus when I search for `loopbaan` using the following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "loopbaan",
            "fields": [
                "content^1.0"
            ],
            "analyzer": "test_analyzer",
            "flags": -1,
            "default_operator": "or",
            "analyze_wildcard": false,
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
            "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
            "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    }
}
```

**I GET NO RESULTS:**

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

**QUESTION**:
How can I get expected results (and I know there are atleast 5 documents which contain the word *"loopbaan"*) by searching for example the word *"loopbaan"*?.

**NOTE:** I know there exists `stemmer-override` in elasticsearch but I want the search to be as general as possible and without me adding words to stemmer-override everytime the dutch stemmer does a bad job. Also I want the plural from of *loopbaan* (which is `loopbanen`) to return exact same results as when I search for *loopbaan*. That is why I use the stemmer.

**this is how I created my *documents* index:**

```
PUT /documents
{
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "content": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "test_synonyms": {
                    "type": "synonym",
                    "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt",
                    "lenient": "true"
                },
                "dutch_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "dutch"
                },
                "dutch_stopwords": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": "_dutch_"
                },
                "test_ascii_folding": {
                    "type": "asciifolding"
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "test_analyzer": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "test_ascii_folding",
                        "dutch_stopwords",
                        "dutch_stemmer",
                        "test_synonyms"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

**2 synonyms for reproduction**:

```
loopbaan, carriere => loopbaan, carriere
schakelen, koppelen, toggelen => schakelen, koppelen, toggelen
```

**3 documents for reproduction (1st and 3rd example should match with `loopbanen` and `loopbaan` as they contain `carriere`**):

```
{
   "title": "Hoezo is dit goed gedaan in het onderwijs?"
   "content": "Werken is goed voor de mensen die in Nederlands wonen. Het verbetert de economie en de welzijn van de mensen. Carrière opbouwen is ook zeer belangrijk voor de specialisatie van de nederlandse mensen in onze samenleving."
}, 
{
   "title": "Dit slaat toch nergens op dat mensen dit kunnen doen."
   "content": "Mensen moeten koppelen. Wat nou "dit" is in deze context weet ik ook niet maar ja zo kan je zien dat elke woord zomaar iets kan betekenen toch? Zou zeggen van wel maar dit heeft niks te maken met iets dus de mazzel."
},
{
   "title": "Werken moet door iedereen gedaan worden en niet alleen door paar mensen in nederland"
   "content": "Werken moet door iedereen gedaan worden en niet alleen door paar mensen in nederland. Het moet echt zo zijn dat mensen carrieres opbouwen en niet alleen thuis zitten, want dat is slecht voor gezondheid van de mensen en de economie over het algemeen."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using one analyzer for indexing and another for searching. The recommended way of doing what you want can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/mixing-exact-search-with-stemming.html)

There are two ways of accomplishing what you need.

1. You can use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/multi-fields.html). You use your custom analyzer for one field and the exact same analyzer that you are using when querying (in this case the standard analyzer which is the default for text and can be ommitted).

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "stemmed": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "test_analyzer"
          }
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "loopbaan",
      "fields": [
        "content^1.0",
        "context.stemmed^1.0"
      ],
      "analyzer": "test_analyzer",
      "flags": -1,
      "default_operator": "or",
      "analyze_wildcard": false,
      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
      "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
      "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
      "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

This solution is quite heavy on your cluster since it will make your index a lot bigger

2. You can modify your query and analyze your query twice and wrap that in a bool query in a should clause. Basically what you do is this

```
Match MY_QUERY(analyzed with my custom analyzer) 
OR 
Match MY_QUERY(by using the same analyzer my field used when it was saved)
```

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "loopbaan",
            "fields": [
              "content^1.0"
            ],
            "analyzer": "test_analyzer",
            "flags": -1,
            "default_operator": "or",
            "analyze_wildcard": false,
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
            "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
            "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "loopbaan",
            "fields": [
              "content^1.0"
            ],
            "flags": -1,
            "default_operator": "or",
            "analyze_wildcard": false,
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
            "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
            "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I would use the second option

In conclusion, you can choose between analyzing your documents twice or analyzing your queries twice. It's up to you.

Update

```
PUT documents
{
  "aliases": {},
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "test_analyzer_without_stemmer"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "test_synonyms": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "loopbaan,carriere,carrieres",
            "schakelen,koppelen,toggelen"
          ],
          "lenient": "true"
        },
        "dutch_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "dutch"
        },
        "dutch_stopwords": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_dutch_"
        },
        "test_ascii_folding": {
          "type": "asciifolding"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "test_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "test_ascii_folding",
            "dutch_stopwords",
            "dutch_stemmer",
            "test_synonyms"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        },
        "test_analyzer_without_stemmer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "test_ascii_folding",
            "dutch_stopwords",
            "test_synonyms"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT documents/_doc/1
{
   "title": "Hoezo is dit goed gedaan in het onderwijs?",
   "content": "Werken is goed voor de mensen die in Nederlands wonen. Het verbetert de economie en de welzijn van de mensen. Carrière opbouwen is ook zeer belangrijk voor de specialisatie van de nederlandse mensen in onze samenleving."
}

PUT documents/_doc/2
{
   "title": "Dit slaat toch nergens op dat mensen dit kunnen doen.",
   "content": "Mensen moeten koppelen. Wat nou \"dit\" is in deze context weet ik ook niet maar ja zo kan je zien dat elke woord zomaar iets kan betekenen toch? Zou zeggen van wel maar dit heeft niks te maken met iets dus de mazzel."
}

PUT documents/_doc/3
{
   "title": "Werken moet door iedereen gedaan worden en niet alleen door paar mensen in nederland",
   "content": "Werken moet door iedereen gedaan worden en niet alleen door paar mensen in nederland. Het moet echt zo zijn dat mensen carrieres opbouwen en niet alleen thuis zitten, want dat is slecht voor gezondheid van de mensen en de economie over het algemeen."
}

GET documents/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "loopbaan",
            "fields": [
              "content"
            ],
            "analyzer": "test_analyzer",
            "flags": -1,
            "default_operator": "or",
            "analyze_wildcard": false,
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
            "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
            "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "loopbaan",
            "fields": [
              "content^1.0"
            ],
            "default_operator": "or",
            "flags": -1,
            "analyze_wildcard": false,
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
            "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
            "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Alkis, thanks very much for your response. I am quite new to Elasticsearch so could you clarify what you mean with 
```Match MY_QUERY(by using the same analyzer my field used when it was saved)```
Because I don't know which analyzer is for index and for search.

Comment: Check out this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html and comment here if you need more

Comment: Oh ok now I understand the difference, though I don't define a search analyzer only my self made custom analyzer. So what is then being used as my standard analyzer in this case?

Comment: There two ways to define  a search analyzer which is different than the analyzer (index/document analyzer). 1. use search_analyzer in your mapping as in the documentation. 2. what you've done, specify an analyzer during your query. So in your case you are analyzing your document with standard analyzer (default for text type) and your query is analyzed with test_analyzer. And that's the problem.

Comment: The second proposal should solve your problem without changing your mapping. Have tried it?

Comment: Yes but when I give "loopbanen" in the search ,which should provide me  with the same search results as when searching for "loopbaan", it returns no results. Only modification I have done is changing the query to yours nothing else.

Comment: Ok please provide a mapping that includes one or two synonyms (inside the mapping, not as a path in a file) and two or three documents so I can reproduce

Comment: I updated the question it now contains examples and synonyms

Comment: It can't match both 1 and 3. In doc 3 you have carrieres in your doc. But you do not want to use stemming in your  docs as you've mentioned. It can work only if you add it as synonym. You can't have it all...

Comment: I mean using stemming is fine by me, the only thing that I don't wanna use is the ```stemmer-override``` as I mentiond in the question. This is not really practical for me as I have more than 1000 documents.